# Media Foundation get IMFMediaType of a topology node

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

I've written an app that's based on the [SampleGrabberSink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/using-the-sample-grabber-sink) example. My application is actually working as I want but one function I needed to perform was to get the video resolution when the .mp4 source changed part way into the file. I eventually worked out how to do it but it seems very long winded and I suspect there must be a simpler way.

In the sample below is there a way to shorten the code block handling the `MESessionStreamSinkFormatChanged` case? It seems like what's taking nearly 40 lines of code (counting initialisation and cleanup) should take 1 or 2.

```
HRESULT RunSession(IMFMediaSession *pSession, IMFTopology *pTopology, OnVideoResolutionChangedFunc onVideoResolutionChanged)
{
  IMFMediaEvent *pEvent = NULL;
  IMFTopologyNode *pNode = nullptr;
  IMFStreamSink *pStreamSink = nullptr;
  IUnknown *pNodeObject = NULL;
  IMFMediaTypeHandler *pMediaTypeHandler = nullptr;
  IMFMediaType *pMediaType = nullptr;

  PROPVARIANT var;
  PropVariantInit(&var);

  HRESULT hr = S_OK;
  CHECK_HR(hr = pSession->SetTopology(0, pTopology));
  CHECK_HR(hr = pSession->Start(&GUID_NULL, &var));

  while(1)
  {
    HRESULT hrStatus = S_OK;
    MediaEventType met;

    CHECK_HR(hr = pSession->GetEvent(0, &pEvent));
    CHECK_HR(hr = pEvent->GetStatus(&hrStatus));
    CHECK_HR(hr = pEvent->GetType(&met));

    if(FAILED(hrStatus))
    {
      printf("Session error: 0x%x (event id: %d)\n", hrStatus, met);
      hr = hrStatus;
      goto done;
    }
    else
    {
      //printf("Session event: event id: %d\n",  met);
      switch(met)
      {
      case MESessionStreamSinkFormatChanged:
        //std::cout << "MESessionStreamSinkFormatChanged." << std::endl;

        {
          MF_TOPOLOGY_TYPE nodeType;
          UINT64 outputNode{0};
          GUID majorMediaType;
          UINT64 videoResolution{0};
          UINT32 stride{0};

          // This seems a ridiculously convoluted way to extract the change to the video resolution. There may
          // be a simpler way but then again this is the Media Foundation and COM!
          CHECK_HR_ERROR(pEvent->GetUINT64(MF_EVENT_OUTPUT_NODE, &outputNode), "Failed to get ouput node from media changed event.");
          CHECK_HR_ERROR(pTopology->GetNodeByID(outputNode, &pNode), "Failed to get topology node for output ID.");
          CHECK_HR_ERROR(pNode->GetObject(&pNodeObject), "Failed to get the node's object pointer.");
          CHECK_HR_ERROR(pNodeObject->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pStreamSink)), "Failed to get media stream sink from activation object.");
          CHECK_HR_ERROR(pStreamSink->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pMediaTypeHandler), "Failed to get media type handler from stream sink.");
          CHECK_HR_ERROR(pMediaTypeHandler->GetCurrentMediaType(&pMediaType), "Failed to get current media type.");
          CHECK_HR_ERROR(pMediaType->GetMajorType(&majorMediaType), "Failed to get major media type.");

          if(majorMediaType == MFMediaType_Video)
          {
            CHECK_HR_ERROR(pMediaType->GetUINT64(MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, &videoResolution), "Failed to get new video resolution.");
            CHECK_HR_ERROR(pMediaType->GetUINT32(MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE, &stride), "Failed to get the new stride.");
            std::cout << "Media session video resolution changed to width " << std::to_string(HI32(videoResolution)) 
              << " and height " << std::to_string(LO32(videoResolution)) 
              << " and stride " << stride << "." << std::endl;
            if(onVideoResolutionChanged != nullptr) {
              onVideoResolutionChanged(HI32(videoResolution), LO32(videoResolution), stride);
            }
          }
          break;
        }
      default:
        break;
      }
    }

    if(met == MESessionEnded)
    {
      break;
    }
    SafeRelease(&pEvent);
    SafeRelease(&pNode);
    SafeRelease(&pStreamSink);
    SafeRelease(&pNodeObject);
    SafeRelease(&pMediaTypeHandler);
    SafeRelease(&pMediaType);
  }

done:
  SafeRelease(&pEvent);
  SafeRelease(&pNode);
  SafeRelease(&pStreamSink);
  SafeRelease(&pNodeObject);
  SafeRelease(&pMediaTypeHandler);
  SafeRelease(&pMediaType);
  return hr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// This seems a ridiculously convoluted way to extract the change to the video resolution. There may
// be a simpler way but then again this is the Media Foundation and COM!
```

The code looks good. You don't need to do everything on resolution change - you can retrieve media type handler just once and keep the pointer when it's needed.

On the entertaining comment above I would say the following. Just like in the case of DirectShow, Sample Grabber is the way to cut corners hard and do something against the design of the pipeline. Almost everyone out there loved DirectShow Sample Grabber and so the future of Media Foundation Sample Grabber could be if there was enough of people who developed for Media Foundation in first place.

Resolution change is generally the business of primitives, i.e. source-transform, transform-transform, and transform-sink connections. Even in this scenario you are getting the notification on resolution change out of band (it's asynchronous notification for you) and you are lucky Media Foundation and its Sample Grabber are so flexible that you can handle this in first place.

To implement this reliably you would normally need a custom media sink, but Sample Grabber lets you cut a corner even at this time.

With custom sink implementation you are guaranteed that you don't receive media sample with new resolution before you agree on new resolution in first place (and you can reject it, of course). With `MESessionStreamSinkFormatChanged` however the event is posted for async retrieval and Sample Grabber continues processing, so technially you can have grabber callbacks with frames of new resolution before you get the session event.

If in your real application you create output node using stream sink and not media sink activate as in your example above, you would not need to retrieve media type handle using topology nodes - you would be able to pull it directly.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I understand what you mean. Prior to SampleGrabber I read samples directly from the IMFSourceReader and handled the MF_SOURCE_READERF_CURRENTMEDIATYPECHANGED events. But that didn't allow me to use the MediaSession for proper sample timing. When I'm feeling brave I'll take another look at the custom media sink.